# Paint Swing Component to PDF using iText

Tags: jframe, itext

I have a JFrame, which i wish to save as a PDF.
How do i paint this JFrame using iText?

```
public PrintFrameToPDF(JFrame bill)  {
    try {
        Document d = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream ("sample.pdf"));

        d.open ();

        // HOW ?

        d.close ();
    }
    catch(Exception e)  {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick (and it's generic for JComponent object):

```
public PrintFrameToPDF(JFrame bill)  {
    try {
        Document d = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream ("sample.pdf"));
        d.open ();

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent( );
        PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
        Graphics2D g2d = template.createGraphics(width, height);
        bill.print(g2d);
        bill.addNotify();
        bill.validate();
        g2d.dispose();

        d.close ();
    }
    catch(Exception e)  {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: I have Passed isntance of JDialog object to this Function. It hrows Exception Error in Print Module The document has no pages.
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(PdfPages.java:113)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1221)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:810)
        at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)