# Vector graphics displayed in GUI

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, vector-graphics

Is it possible to load vector image (for example .svg, .cdr, .pdf) in `JFrame` or `Applet`?

Comment: for pdf in jframe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109145/paint-swing-component-to-pdf-using-itext

Comment: for svg java example see https://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Graphic-Library/jgraph/com/jgraph/layout/svg/SVGExample.java.htm

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot ;). I don't know why I didnt see/search that before.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Apache Batik SVG Toolkit](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/). It's free.